# Swift IBAction Issue With ViewController Swap OSX

Tags: macos, swift, viewcontroller, ibaction

I have 2 ViewControllers in an OSX swift project using storyboards. My aim is, when I click the button, the IBAction is called and the view also switches. However, despite my IBAction seeming to be good (I dragged it on and did  println("hi")) "hi" is not printed, but the viewcontroller is changed. I would think it were an XCode glitch if I didn't know better, but for the life of me I can't think of what I'm doing wrong. Is anyone able to replicate this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you paste the ViewController code? Is this the first time you hooked up an IBAction to that button? There might be an existing connection in the connections inspector which you haven't closed out yet?

Comment: The important parts are as follows:

`class JammingControlleur: NSViewController, NSTableViewDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource, NSTextFieldDelegate {
<br>
var SVCInstance: SomethingViewController = SomethingViewController()`

.....

`@IBAction func saveoir(sender: AnyObject) {
        
        println("The tempos is \(tempoShow.integerValue) bpm")
        
        SVCInstance.saveoirHasBeenCalledWith(tempoShow.integerValue)

    }
`

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to format it well, but that's the idea